# passing tuple to ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, tuples

I am currently using a case statement to determine the correct flow.
It looks like this:

```
case os
  when 'windows'
  # If Windows - Call code for WinRM connection
  when 'redhat'
  # If Redhat - Call code for SSH connection
    if env == 'pci'
      # Do stuff for PCI
      exec_pci
    else
      # Do stuff for non PCI
      exec_non_pci
    end
  else
    # Raise some exception
end
```

I know that hash/dictionaries use a single key to look up a value(s) but is it possible to setup a lookup hashtable where I could pass it a tuple?

Im looking to do something like this:

```
os = 'redhat'
env = 'pci'
```

Where I would call the following: `my_hash[(os, env)]` and expecting to receive a value returned like `exec_pci`

Comment: Ruby cannot do that. But I think you could customize your own Tuple class, then use tuple object as key.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Ruby doesn't have tuples. Are you talking about a tuple implementation you wrote yourself? If yes, please show your code. Are you talking about some third-party tuple library? If yes, which one? Either way, Ruby doesn't allow libraries to change the syntax and semantics of the language, so `(os, env)` is simply illegal syntax (unless it is as part of a parameter list or argument list).

Comment: Also, a Yes/No question like "is it possible to" is a really bad fit for [so]. There are only two possible answers: "No" (which doesn't help either you or anybody else a bit) or "Yes" (which still doesn't help either your or anybody else a bit).

Comment: If you write `case [os, env]` the `when` clause for `”windows”` must be written `when [“windows”, x]’, where ‘x’ is an arbitrary value that is disregarded by that clause. That is, in my opinion, bad programming practice, not to mentioned that it’s really ugly. My advice: don’t do it.

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to use a `Hash` for this? Seems like a simple class would be far better and the delegation of `pci` or `non_pci` should be handled by the executor not the conditional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The monster here is the `else` clause in your original code. If you can get rid of it, then you can make a hash for lookup.

```
my_hash = {
  ['windows', nil] => -> { exec_windows },
  ['redhat', 'pci'] => -> { exec_pci },
  ['redhat', 'non_pci'] => -> { exec_non_pci }
}

os, env = 'windows', nil

my_hash[[os, env]].call
```

Note that querying a hash by key requires exact matches, so for example, if your `os` is `'windows'`, the `env` must be `nil`, otherwise you'll get a `NoMethodError` telling you that `nil` has no method named `call`. You can make this error thrown a little bit earlier by using `Hash#fetch`

```
my_hash.fetch([os, env]).call
```

The other caveat is that you have to define `my_hash` in the same scope where the job (e.g. `exec_pci`) is supposed to be called, otherwise you may not be able to call those methods correctly.

Comment: Could the `else` clause not be handled by attaching a [Hash#default_proc](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) to the hash?

Comment: Not if you have multiple `else`.

Comment: I didn't read the OP's code carefully enough. Note that the question does not specify that there are only two possible values for `env`. For all we know, the possible values of `env` may not even be known at compile-time. The OP is only concerned if it is `pci` or something else. Also, don't you think `['windows', nil]` is a bit klutzy?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think all possible `env` should be known at compile-time, otherwise it will be a security issue. I admit that `['windows', nil]` is very clumsy, but I can't find another way to make the interface identical to windows and redhat. If the OP uses Elixir, the code should look prettier thanks to the pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do that as follows.

```
def doit(os, *ssh)
  case os
  when 'windows'
    puts "os = 'windows'" # remove when debugged
    raise ArgumentError unless ssh.empty?
    # Call code for WinRM connection
  when 'redhat'
    puts "os = 'redhat'" # remove when debugged
    puts "ssh = #{ssh}" # remove when debugged
    raise ArgumentError unless ssh.size == 1
    # Call code for SSH connection
    if ssh.first == 'pci'
      # Do stuff for PCI
      exec_pci
    else
      # Do stuff for non PCI
      exec_non_pci
    end
  else
    puts "os != 'windows' and os != 'redhat'" # remove when debugged
    # Raise an exception
    raise StandardError
  end
end

def exec_pci
  puts "exec_pic called"
end

def exec_non_pci
  puts "exec_non_pic called"
end
```

```
doit 'windows'
  #-> os = 'windows'
doit 'windows', 'cat'
  #-> os = 'windows'
  #=> ArgumentError: ArgumentError
doit 'redhat', 'pci'
  #-> os = 'redhat'
  #-> ssh = ["pci"]
  #-> exec_non_pic called
doit 'redhat', 'cat'
  #-> os = 'redhat'
  #-> ssh = ["cat"]
  #-> exec_non_pic called
doit 'redhat'
  #-> os = 'redhat'
  #-> ssh = []
  #=> ArgumentError: ArgumentError
doit 'redhat', 'cat', 'dog'
  #-> os = 'redhat'
  #=> ssh = ["cat", "dog"]
  #=> ArgumentError: ArgumentError
doit 'cat'
  #-> os != 'windows' and os != 'redhat'
  #=> StandardError: StandardError
```

If have assumed `exec_pci` and `exec_non_pci` are unstated methods. If they are instead local variables not shown in the question, one would need to modify the method `doit` so that it would be called, for example,

```
doit 'redhat', 'pci', exec_pic
```

To call `doit('windows', arg)`, where `arg` is artificial value (e.g., `nil`) that is not used, is in my opinion bad programming practice.